# Navigate the Link opened in IE to Mozilla

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I want to force the user to open the Link in Mozilla.

Even When the User opens the link in IE, the link should be navigated to the Mozilla Browser using JQuery or Java Script.

Thanks!

Comment: Short of using feature detection and wiping out the DOM and replacing with a message like "You must open this link in Firefox.", I'm pretty sure you can't accomplish the behavior you're looking for unless you have control of the client.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible browser side. Is there a reason to not just tell the user that IE is not supported and suggest that they open in Firefox?

Comment: JSF rendering of images and few ajax calls works properly in Mozilla, but not in IE. until I find the solution in the IE, I trying to restrict the user to use Mozilla alone.

Answer (score 3):

Executing programs from JavaScript or JQuery is impossible. If this sort of behavior was allowed it would pose a security risk seeing as any website you would go to would be able open up programs on your PC. The only thing you could do, as other commenters have mentioned, is simply prompt the user to use Mozilla Firefox. This could be accomplished like so.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') == -1){
    alert("Please view this webpage with the Mozilla Firefox web browser.")
}
```

You could even bind some code to the anchor tag's click event ensuring that only users running Firefox would be redirected and that users of other browsers would receive an alert prompting them to switch.

Comment: I have achieved the same using the below Java Script:function checkBrowser() {
 if ($.browser.mozilla) {} 
 else {
    alert('Please view this webpage with the Mozilla Firefox web browser.');
 } 
}

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as described by others many reasons wrong with it.

Your main issue which you should be looking into is why your application isn't working in IE.

JSF works and supports IE browsers, (newer versions mostly of course) and JSF UI Libraries like PrimeFaces, IceFaces, RichFaces all now support IE to some degree with there components.

Maybe post the error you're getting in IE and what component etc.